# Redirect version.appidentifier.appspot.com to my own domain's subdomain

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a GAE app and I have already been able to redirect *appidentifier.appspot.com* to my own domain's www subdomain and the naked domain. For example, if I owned *foo.appspot.com* and *foo.com*, then entering in *www.foo.com* or *foo.com* into the browser will render the contents of *foo.appspot.com* successfully. I configured all this using **Google Apps** on the Google side of things and **NameCheap** on the registrar side of things.

Now, I have made a new, non-default version of my GAE app. Let's call it *dev.foo.appspot.com*. How do I set up a URL forward (or what-not) so that I can access this GAE version by simply entering *dev.foo.com* into my browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for to do is possible if you set up a wildcard subdomain mapping. This is well documented in the final section of [Using a Custom Domain](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain).

Comment: Thank for the help. I do need to add that Google's page is a little outdated. The "Add URL" button is no longer on the **Dashboard** page. Instead, you have to go to **Settings** then go to the link on the left toolbar for your App Engine app.